# How to pass atributes to a method in a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods

Trying to get the hang of classes, can anyone tell me how to get my method "attack" to add the baseDamage to the damage? currently it just prints the "damage" and doesn't add the baseDamage to it.

```
from random import randint

class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, name, baseDamage, price):
        self.name = name
        self.baseDamage = baseDamage
        self.price = price
    def attack(self):
        damage = randint(1,10)
        self.baseDamage + damage
        return damage

def main():
    steelSword = Weapon("Steel Longsword", 10, 250)
    print("Name:", steelSword.name, "\nDamage:", steelSword.baseDamage, "\nPrice:", steelSword.price,"coins")
    print(steelSword.attack())

main()
```

Comment: Since you removed your other question: I highly recommend a tutorial that covers the basics of object oriented programming. [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist - Learning with Python](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/index.html) is pretty good, take a look at chapter [13. Classes and objects](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch13.html) and the two following chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.baseDamage += damage
```

OR

```
self.baseDamage = self.baseDamage + damage
```

Comment: God how did I miss that! and I just realised it's damage += self.baseDamage += damage

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your new value back to self.baseDamage. Your line here:

```
self.baseDamage + damage
```

Is not storing the result anywhere. To do this, you want to assign it back to `self.baseDamage` like this:

```
self.baseDamage += damage
```

To expand that, it is similar to writing it out like this:

```
self.baseDamage = self.baseDamage + damage
```

You could even further simplify and do this:

```
self.baseDamage += randint(1,10)
```

Also, you should make sure what it is you want to return. If you return damage, you are not returning the "baseDamage + damage". Maybe you want to return self.baseDamage after you performed your attack calculation?